# How do I convert 1-dimensional array of String to String?

Tags: vb.net

Is there an easy way to convert a 1-dimensional array of String to a normal String? I'm new to vb.net

Comment: Have a look at `String.Concat` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd784338(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: If you are currently asking this because you are getting an error message, then you are doing something wrong; converting to a string is most likely not the way to solve the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `String.Join(",", myArray)` or however else you'd like to join them. The first parameter is just what you'd like to put between each of the strings you are joining. Use vbCrLf for a new line.

Answer (score 3):

Try `String.Concat` if you want just to glue the items together (`["A", "B", "CD"] -> "ABCD"`):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd784338(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2

```
 Dim output As String = String.Concat(myArray);
```

If you want to *separate* values of the array (`["A", "B", "CD"] -> "A, B, CD"`), try `String.Join`:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783876(v=vs.110).aspx

```
 Dim output As String = String.Join(", ", myArray);
```